# Hamamatsu camera python

Tags: python, image, compiler-errors, camera, package

I try to talk to my Hamamatsu camera with python. I installed the package like explained in https://pypi.org/project/hamamatsu/#description.

Here again the usage code:

```
from hamamatsu.dcam import dcam, Stream

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

with dcam:
    camera = dcam[0]
    with camera:
        print(camera.info)
        print(camera['image_width'].value, camera['image_height'].value)

        # Simple acquisition example
        nb_frames = 10
        camera["exposure_time"] = 0.1
        with Stream(camera, nb_frames) as stream:
                logging.info("start acquisition")
                camera.start()
                for i, frame_buffer in enumerate(stream):
                    frame = copy_frame(frame_buffer)
                    logging.info(f"acquired frame #%d/%d: %s", i+1, nb_frames, frame)
                logging.info("finished acquisition")
```

When executing this, I get the following error:
`NameError: name 'copy_frame' is not defined`. I couldn't find out from which package copy_frame is. Can anybode help me?

Answer (score 0):

(https://github.com/tiagocoutinho/hamamatsu/blob/master/hamamatsu/dcam.py).

```
from hamamatsu.dcam import dcam, Stream, copy_frame
```

should do.

You also forgot the first line of the example

```
import logging
```